# Primefaces gerando arquivo primefaces.css.html

Tags: css, primefaces

Primefaces está gerando arquivos css e js com extensão .html, por exemplo, primefaces.css.html.

Esse arquivo é relatado como uma vulnerabilidade potencial.

Alguém sabe como este arquivo é generatede? Como posso mudar isso?

Comment: É um projeto novo ?

Comment: Não. É um porjeto antigo, com JSF 2.1 e Primefaces 5.1